# Command Line Git Problems

Tags: git, shell, github, command

I'm not fully understanding git. I have a repository on github.com which I checkout by cloning. Then I add a file called index.html and commit via command line. Then nothing happens on github.com. I cannot see the new file updating nor do I see any of the new branches I create. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: push the change to github.com? git push origin my-branch-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to commit it's not enough.

please run one more command:

```
git push origin <your_branch_name>
```

after this command your new branch will be created on github with your commited changes

Answer (score 1):

How are you making your commits Kolob?

Before you commit your changes you need to stage them by typing something like `git add .` `git add` takes an argument of a file path to upload, in this case `.` will add your current directory.

After you add the files you can then type `git commit -m "commit message"` to commit your changes.

Once you do that you can type `git push origin <your_branch_name>` to push your changes to the remote repo.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
git status
```

If you have "??" before the file name you have to

```
git add <file>
```

or

```
git add .
```

that adds all the files.

Then the commit. And after that you should do:

```
git push origin <your_branch_name>
```

More info [here](http://gitref.org/basic/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
git push origin <local branch>:<remote branch>
```

to push code in git where origin, local branch, and remote branch are optional. Then when you want to get your changes from the remote repository you can use:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/<branchname>
```

Ideally you would use fetch instead of pull as this allows you to analyse the remote changes before you merge. You can view the remote changes by showing a full tree of your branches like so:

```
git log --oneline --all --decorate --graph
```

I have this command aliased as "gg" to make it quicker.